# Query storage status on an RDS DB using AWS CLI

Tags: storage, monitoring, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I have a few RDS servers I'd like to monitor for insufficient disk space. For simplicity sake, I prefer using my current monitoring system rather than an AWS solution like cloudwatch.

I've been [reading the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/) and the nearest solution was [`describe-db-instances`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html), which gives the allocated storage, but not the space left / amount of storage used:

```
"SecondaryAvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
"ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers": [],
"AllocatedStorage": 100,
...
```

**How do I query a specific RDS DB instance for the amount of free space left or used?**

Answer (score 1):

The right tool is the [cloudwatch CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html):

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics             \
               --metric-name FreeStorageSpace    \
               --start-time 2017-02-27T23:00:00Z \ 
               --end-time 2017-02-28T23:00:00Z   \
               --period 3600                     \
               --namespace AWS/RDS               \
               --statistics Average              \  
               --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=<DB-NAME>
```

`<DB-NAME>` and the metric name `FreeStorageSpace` can be found using:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics
```